# Search numbers using elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have some records with id property so I need to search my id field using Elasticsearch. But the user doesn't have exact id so Once the user tries with a partial number if it matches partially should return the result.

For an example, Id is 1234 once I type 12 should return this record
Any idea of how to do string contains (*) behavior for numeric values?

Answer (score 1):

if you care about the prefix search ie for id `1234` only when user start the search for `12` it should return id and not for `23`, then it will be more performant and can easily be implemented using the [perfix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) in Elasticsearch.

If you want `1234` even when the user misses beginning char and search for `23`, then you can need to create a custom analyzer using [n-gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html), which will create tokens like `12`, `23`, `34`, `123`, `234` like so that you can provide infix search as well.

Note: Both `prefix queries` and `n-gram tokenizer` are not applicable to a numeric field. you need to store your user id in the text field to make it work.

**Working example for `n-gram tokenizer` as requested in comment**

**Index def**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index.max_ngram_diff": 10,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": { 
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "uid": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer" : "standard"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index sample doc**

```
{
    "uid" : "1234"
}
```

**Search query for `12` **

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "uid" : {
                "query" : "12"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "intdata",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.45532417,
                "_source": {
                    "uid": "1234"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Similarly, it would return result for `23` , `123`, `34` etc

Comment: Thank you so much .Any better example for n-gram tokenizer ?